How to store a relation without an Id property in EF Core
Using EF Core, I would like to create a relation in my model without explicitly declaring a property referencing the other class ID.
For example, imagine these 2 classes, from the official EF Core documentation :
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string BlogUrl { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

If I want to access the blog URL from the blog post I can use myBlogPost.Blog.Url.
The BlogUrl property is redundant here.
What is the correct way to create the Post class without including a BlogUrl property?

How do you define "correct" here? When you use EF code-first you're surrendering a lot of control of your DB to EF which can result in denormalizations which RDBMS purists like myself consider "incorrect" (and I note that you're using the term "relation" incorrectly here...)

I think you misunderstood the documentation; the section you read is about using BlogUrl as an alternate key, not omitting the BlogId from the Post class which is what you appear to want to do?

Using myBlogPost.Blog.Url is the correct way. We do not want to de-normalize the schema. Having a BlogUrl property declared in Post would have EF expecting that column in the Post table, which we do not want. We can mark such properties for EF to ignore. For example:
[NotMapped]
public string? BlogUrl => Blog?.Url;

However there is a few caveats with this approach. Firstly, the value is only available if we eager load Blog, or have lazy loading enabled and the DbContext that loaded Post is still in scope when BlogUrl is accessed. We also cannot use BlogUrl in any Linq expressions. For instance:
var posts = _context.Posts
    .Where(p => p.BlogUrl == url)
    .ToList();

This isn't allowed. EF does not know what BlogUrl is, it cannot be translated down to SQL.
Now, if you are loading a list of posts to display and want to include their URL without fetching the entire Post an Blog for each row like:
var posts = _context.Posts
    .Include(p => p.Blog)
    .Where(p => p.PostDate >= startDate)
    .ToList();

Whether you want to use post.Blog.Url or the unmapped helper post.BlogUrl.
Say you just want the Post ID, Title, and Blog Url, then this is where projection comes into play. We create a view model representing just the details we want for the view:
public class PostSummaryViewModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BlogUrl { get; set; }
}

Now to fetch and populate the view model:
var posts = _context.Posts
    .Where(p => p.PostDate >= startDate)
    .Select(p => new PostSummaryViewModel
    {
        PostId = p.PostId,
        Title = p.Title,
        BlogUrl = p.Blog.Url
    }).ToList();

EF will generate a query from Post and the related Blog to fetch back just the 3 columns we need to populate the view model. You can utilize a mapper like Automapper or Mapperly etc. to configure the mapping rules between entity -> VM (and back) then simplify that to:
var posts = _context.Posts
    .Where(p => p.PostDate >= startDate)
    .ProjectTo<PostSummaryViewModel>(config)
    .ToList();

ViewModels or DTOs are the recommended way to fetch and serve data for consumers rather than passing entities. They allow you to minimize the amount of data fetched, but also provide a clean separation for things like formatting or flattening data to suit consumption without tainting the entities. EF entities should be concerned with purely data domain concerns while view models can be concerned with view domain needs.
